# Handling large lists with wso2

Tags: json, list, parsing, wso2, size

I'm using the wso2 integration studio 7.1.0.
When I'm trying to modify the obtained payload from an external endpoint call, if the endpoint response has a list longer than 4549 elements, than the JsonXMLStreamReader gives a StackOverflowError.
This problem occurs with several mediators: Iterator, PayloadFactory, Script...
I've already checked the JVM memory parameters and I've already tried to change the axis2 JsonFormatter and JsonBuilder.

The simplest example I tried is to call the end point that returns a json holding a list of integers. Then a Script mediator with nashornJS takes the payload add field to the json and reset the payload. If the returned list from the endpoint is smaller than 4549 elements it works correctly, otherwise it gets a StackOverflowError exception.

wso2 code:

```
 <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/cc">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="l2-prova"/>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/dd">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="l2-prova"/>
            </call>
            <script language="nashornJs"><![CDATA[body = mc.getPayloadJSON();
body.len = body.list.length
mc.setPayloadJSON(body)]]></script>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

exception:

```
[2020-11-04 10:55:53,044] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} - Uncaught exception java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.yytext(JsonScanner.java:481)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.yylex(JsonScanner.java:903)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonScanner.nextSymbol(JsonScanner.java:310)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.next(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.peek(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

When JsonXMLStreamReader consuming the json payload, it goes through the following method call.

https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/commons/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/commons/staxon/core/json/JsonXMLStreamReader.java#L149

The above is a recursive method that is consuming the stack until it finishes reading the last element of the array.

Hence, the StackOverflow error is causing by a large number of array elements.

try to increase the stack size from the JVM and check again.